# VueJs: Only precompiling HTML templates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-loader

I'm currently using VueJS but the startup performance is not as good as I would want it to be.

When loading a new page, a lot of the time is spent in `compileToFunctions` and `parseHTML`.

My project isn't compatible with Webpack and with the vue-loader because of the script/javascript section. I know it's not ideal but that's how it is.

Is there a way to precompile only the HTML portion of the `.vue` file and then provide the script section later?

Comment: "_My project isn't compatible with Webpack and with the vue-loader because of the script/javascript section_" that sounds like a very uncommon constraint, so if you do not share more details / code on that, I doubt you could get any relevant answer.

Comment: Can you use Browserify?

Comment: @ghybs The website was not designed to work with Webpack. Refactoring the website to be compiled with Webpack would be too expensive.

Comment: Thanks for the message, but you are not improving your explanation at all. While we may understand that you cannot / do not want to adapt your code to fit webpack / browserify / whatever build engine, since you do not show a detailed code example of this particular architecture, and this constraint sounds so uncommon, how do you expect people to be able to help you with a relevant solution?

Comment: @ghybs The architecture doesn't matter. What I am asking is if it's possible to  precompile only the HTML section of a vue template. That's it. The way the javascript is handled isn't relevant to the question.

Comment: While there is surely an answer to "_precompile only the HTML section of a vue template_", it still sounds to me that such a solution would not fit with your architecture if you are unable to use a build tool. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML template can be precompiled by exposing and filling `functionCompileCache`. It's as simple as that.